# NoClassDefFoundError: QuerydslUtils

Tags: java, spring-data, amazon-dynamodb

Getting `NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/querydsl/QuerydslUtils error`. 
I am using 1.13.6.RELEASE version of spring-data-commons.

The stack trace is as follows:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/querydsl/QuerydslUtils
    at org.socialsignin.spring.data.dynamodb.repository.support.DynamoDBRepositoryFactory.isQueryDslRepository(DynamoDBRepositoryFactory.java:142) ~[spring-data-dynamodb-5.0.2.jar:5.0.2]
    at org.socialsignin.spring.data.dynamodb.repository.support.DynamoDBRepositoryFactory.getRepositoryBaseClass(DynamoDBRepositoryFactory.java:135) ~[spring-data-dynamodb-5.0.2.jar:5.0.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepositoryInformation(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:253) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:195) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:277) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:263) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    ... 29 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.data.querydsl.QuerydslUtils
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    ... 37 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Are you using <dependency>
  <groupId>com.github.derjust</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-data-dynamodb</artifactId>
  <version>5.0.2</version>
</dependency>?

Comment: I am not sure whether you directly downloaded the jar and try using it. If you use Maven, it will automatically download the dependent jars like QuerydslUtils. I have checked the version spring-data-commons 2.0.1.RELEASE. It does have the class QuerydslUtils.

Comment: Yes I am using the 5.0.2 version of spring-data-dynamodb. I am using 1.5.6 Spring boot which is not compatible with 5.0.2 of spring-data-dynamodb
So its a compatibility issue,
Check the below link:
https://github.com/derjust/spring-data-dynamodb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As outlined by @himanshuraipur there is a clash of versions:

`spring-data-dynamodb` `5.0.2` is based on `spring-data` `2.0` / Spring 5.

But `spring-boot` `1.5.6` comes with `spring-data` `1`.

Thus your only chance is to either update your `spring-boot` dependency or go back to `spring-data-dynamodb` `4.5` or `4.6`.
On the project page there is a full [compatibilty matrix](https://github.com/derjust/spring-data-dynamodb#version--spring-framework-compatibility)

Note: I'm the maintainer of the `spring-data-dynamodb` project