# DynamoDB - repository bean not found

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to use spring boot together with DynamoDB. This is the hierarchy of the project:

[image]

I have the following error

```
WARN 79115 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'webController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'klit.demo.repo.CustomerRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Those are my classes

```
@EnableScan
public interface CustomerRepository extends CrudRepository<Customer, String>{
}
```

---

```
@RestController
public class WebController {
    @Autowired
    CustomerRepository repository;

    @RequestMapping("/save")
    public String save() {
        repository.save(new Customer("JSA-1", "Jack", "Smith"));
        return "Done";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/findall")
    public String findAll() {
        String result = "";
        Iterable<Customer> customers = repository.findAll();

        for (Customer cust : customers) {
            result += cust.toString() + "<br>";
        }

        return result;
    }

}
```

---

it doesn't not recognize the repository as a bean ...

Comment: I realise my base package in the configuration class was wrong, but now I have the following error: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customerRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/querydsl/QueryDslUtils

Comment: problem solved following this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50390485/noclassdeffounderror-querydslutils